# Strange behavior of TextIOWrapper.tell() with Python 3.6.9 in context of 0D/0A

Tags: python, file-io, stream

**ENVIRONMENT**:

> ```
> Intel/88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 11 20:11:34 UTC 2020
> Python 3.6.9
> ```

**GIVEN**:

A tiny program stored in `test.py` which shows input position and input character code for the consecutive reading of single characters.

```
fh  = open("tmp.txt", "r")
while 1 + 1 == 2:
    tmp = fh.read(1)
    if not tmp: break
    print(fh.tell(), "%x" % ord(tmp))
```

Fill a `tmp.txt` in bash to contain some data

```
echo -e "\x41\x42\x3b\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a" > tmp.txt
```

**OUTPUT**:

Running `python3 test.py` delivers

```
1 41
2 42
18446744073709551620 3b
5 a
7 a
8 a
```

**QUESTION**:

Where does the excessively high value `18446744073709551620` for `fh.tell()` come from? Interestingly,
this does not happen in the following cases.

```
echo -e "\x41\x42\x3b\x0d\x0a" > tmp.txt     # only one 0x0d/0x0a
echo -e "\x42\x3b\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a" > tmp.txt # no 'A' at the beginning of the file
```

Comment: [Docs for tell](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell): "Return the current stream position as an opaque number. The number does not usually represent a number of bytes in the underlying binary storage."

Comment: Correct, in particular when files are opened in text mode. However, one should expect that if letter Y comes after letter X in the stream, that position(Y) > position(X). Otherwise, stream navigation becomes a complete mess.

Comment: It looks to me as if TextIOBase.tell returns the output of [this function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/83fc70159b24f5b11a5ef87c9b05c2cf4c7faeba/Modules/_io/textio.c#L2024) (but I'm not a C-programmer, so by all means verify).  Why it is implemented like this I don't know.